# Flipping a div (front/back) using jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, flip

I have searched similar questions but came up with nothing.

I am currently trying to make a image flip upon a button click, from front.png to back.png. I also want to dynamically be able to change the back.png to another image through javascript. So its not always the same image when it is fipped.

I tried using the plugin found on https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/ but could not change the back.png

Here is what I have which doesnt work... the front.png shows up and back.png does nothing. Thanks in advance.

```js
$("#hiddencard").flip({
      axis: 'y',
  trigger: 'click'
});

x = document.getElementsByClassName("back"); 
x.src = "different.png";
```

```css
.front {
    position: absolute;
    left:10px;
    bottom:433px;
}​

.back {
 position: absolute;
    left:10px;
    bottom:433px;
}​
```

```html
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/nnattawat/flip/master/dist/jquery.flip.min.js"></script>

<div id="hiddencard"> 
  <div class="front"> 
   <img src="front.png" alt="logo front" />
  </div> 
  <div class="back">
    <img src="back.png" alt="logo back" />
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Which reason speaks for to include jquery twice?

Comment: `x = document.getElementsByClassName("back");` returns all elements with class «back». You need, for example, `x[0].src = 'back.png';` Also, for `src` to make sense, `x[0]` should be an image.

Comment: my original script src was just jquery.flip.min.js, but copy pasted the .com version, and also copy pasted the older version of jquery in. Definitely not on purpose.

Comment: Thank you, x[0].src and changing the html to 

<div id="hiddencard"> 
  <div class="front"> 
   <img src="back.png" alt="logo front" />
  </div> 
  <div class="back">
    <img class= "back1" src="001s.png" alt="logo front" />
  </div> 
</div>

worked